# Decimal point alignment in iOS UILabel during countdown?

Tags: ios, uilabel, number-formatting, countdown

Sorry I don't have any code yet, but would appreciate some advice!

I have a countdown timer showing seconds with one decimal point in a UILabel (10.0, 9.9, 9.8, etc.). It works fine, but the decimal point moves around slightly depending on the size decimal value. Is there a way to align the text in the UILabel to the decimal point or should I create two labels (one for the seconds value aligned right and one for the decimal value aligned left)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your suggestion of multiple labels is perfectly valid.
Here is an attributed string solution (for m:ss but it should work with floating point numbers also):

```
    let string = "\t43:21" // Sample min:sec. Note the leading tab is required in this code.

    let countdownFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
    let terminators = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\t:.") // in some locales '.' is used instead of ':'
    let tabStop = NSTextTab(textAlignment: .Right, location: 40, options: [NSTabColumnTerminatorsAttributeName: terminators])

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [tabStop]

    let attributeDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName: countdownFont]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributeDictionary)
    self.countdownLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Related resources:

https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/string-rendering/#tables-with-numbers

https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920034261/programming-ios-8-1st-edition/314.xhtml?ref=toc#_tab_stops

Of course a fixed width font, such as Courier or Menlo could also solve this problem, but they contrast fairly starkly.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. So for my terminators, I'm using "\t.", but I'm confused about the location for the tabStop (40) compared to the firstLineHeadIndent (20). I assume the decimal should appear at the 40 position and that the \t in the string is needed to "tab over" to the tabStop, but what does the 20 do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the firstLineHeadIndent (20) is not doing anything in this example so I will remove it. The decimal point will be indented 40 points to the right with or without it.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down my problem. The above code works perfectly for my UILabel, but only if the location is set to 27 or lower. When I set it to 28 or higher, the text moves to the right about 8 points (guessing) and is left-justified. Any ideas? Note that the UILabel is in a UITableViewCell defined in my storyboard, and I've set it to both "plain" and "attributed" with the same result.

Comment: I suspect your integer portion (left of the decimal point) is more than 27 points wide. If your text is already past a tab stop I believe it will ignore it, as it would in a text editor (but I am not an expert in this). Make sure the tab stop location is greater than the widest text to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: I ended using Menlo font for timer instead of tabStops. It looked nice enough, was easier to keep centered (e.g. double vs. single digit seconds), and I didn't have to worry about auto layout and size classes for the iPad!